# Тестирование с Jest и Enzyme - изменение состояния

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest, enzyme

Возникла проблема с тестированием реакт компонента. В нем есть функция, реализующая fetch и меняющая состояние с полученными данными:

```
dbSelectRequest = (url) => {
    fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      credentials: 'same-origin',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          [tableName]: response[tableName]
        });
        console.log('---------------STATE AFTER CH----------------', this.state.settings_group)
      });
  };
```

Тест:

```
let data = [something]
test('получение данных о группах пользователя', async () => {
    const props = {
      userId: 1
    }
    const wrapper = mount(<Settings {...props}/>);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    await fetch.mockResponse(JSON.stringify({settings_group: [data]}));
    await instance.dbSelectRequest('settings_group', 0);
    await expect(wrapper.state().settings_group).toEqual(data);
     });
```

Для моков использую пакет jest-fetch-mock.
Суть проблемы: тест не проходит, тк состояние инстанса не меняется (остается пустым), при этом console.log, написанный в функции, выводит состояние как успешно измененное (тоесть заполненное данными data). Как так? Почему они разные?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> при этом console.log, написанный в функции, выводит состояние как успешно измененное (тоесть заполненное данными data).

А точно?

Просто, `setState` сам по себе асинхронный, сразу значение он не поменяет.
Так же у вас `dbSelectRequest` не возвращает `Promise`, то есть `await dbSelectRequest(...)` по сути ничего не дожидается. Надо как минимум `return fetch`, что бы возвращался `Promise`.

Что бы дождаться `update` стейта, можно просто дождаться следующего тика. Типо, что-нибудь вроде:

```
const waitUpdateState = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
     setTimeout(resolve, 0);
  });
}
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста написанную функцию. Ее нужно использовать в самих тестах, верно? Вызвав с await?

Comment: @8Irbis8 да, все что она делает - дожидается следующего таска ( стейт реакта обновляется в микротаске ), использовать типо так
`await waitUpdateState()`